# Backbone Collections Custom Events with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, backbone.js

Can Collection instance be binded to a custom event? I tried it with jQuery: `$(collectionInstance).on(eventsmap)`.

When I then try to check registered events:

`console.log($.data(collectionInstance, 'events'));`

I get all custom events I bound to an instance.

But `$(collection).trigger('customevent');` doesn't fire this customevent and event handler is not called.

When I try the same with `Backbone.View` I can trigger custom events whithout any problems. Why is like that? Am I missing something?

Comment: wouldn't you fire the event on the collectionInstance and not the jquery object?  If i'm not mistaken that may be your problem.  The problem is your object knows about it's own bound events but it, as a jquery object, has no idea what kind of object (backbone collection) it is.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the collection in jQuery? Backbone collections have nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: To make use of jQuery events api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone collections have [`Backbone.Events`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) mixed in so collections have `on`, `off`, and `trigger` methods. You want to use those methods rather than trying to wrap the collection in jQuery:

```
collectionInstance.on('event', callback, context);
// One by one until you're done
```

and then elsewhere:

```
collection.trigger('customevent');
```